# C++ Create fixed size queue

Tags: c++, queue

In **C++**, how do you create a simple **fixed size queue**?

I have done it multiple times in Java and Python but am looking for a C++ based way of doing so.

I need a simple FIFO queue with only 2 elements in order to use the `push` and `pop` utilities: I am already aware of the fact that I could implement my own class to perform this kind of restriction but my question aims to know if there exist any already available solution to this.

Or is it maybe possible to accomplish the same task with an array? That would work as well.

Comment: You have to implement required limited container and use `std::queue` adapter.

Comment: @S.M. thanks, could you please elaborate a bit more about this?

Comment: You have to implement at least `push_back`, `pop_front`, and `size` methods in your container and use it in `std::queue`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could inherit from queue, and then reimplement the push method. Here is a basic example.

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int MaxLen, typename Container=std::deque<T>>
class FixedQueue : public std::queue<T, Container> {
public:
    void push(const T& value) {
        if (this->size() == MaxLen) {
           this->c.pop_front();
        }
        std::queue<T, Container>::push(value);
    }
};

int main() {
    FixedQueue<int, 3> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(5);
    q.push(6);
    q.push(7);

    while (q.size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << q.front() << std::endl;
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

This will print

```
$ g++ fixedqueue.cpp -std=c++17 -o fixedqueue && ./fixedqueue
5
6
7
```

Comment: what is c here?

Comment: @KumarRoshanMehta I think thats a typo, `this->pop_front();` should work.

Answer (score 12):

> In C++, how do you create a simple **fixed size queue**?

First, I think what you actually want is a **fixed-capacity queue**, i.e., the queue's size will be itself limited to the queue's capacity, but the size may vary. For example, the size can be initially zero if the queue is empty and increase up to the queue's capacity as you insert elements into the queue.

---

#### Using `boost::circular_buffer`

The Boost Libraries have the library [**Boost.CircularBuffer**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) that implements the `boost::circular_buffer` container (`boost/circular_buffer.hpp`). This container is suitable as a fixed-capacity FIFO.

Unlike `std::vector`, `boost::circular_buffer`'s *capacity* remains constant regardless of how many elements you insert into the container. That is, no reallocation happens behind the scenes: if `boost::circular_buffer`'s *size* reaches its *capacity*, then the insertion of new elements simply overwrites the existing ones.

You can specify `boost::circular_buffer`'s capacity at construction:

```
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(2);
```

`cb`'s capacity is *2*, and its initial size is zero because the container is empty. Its size can never exceed its capacity. You can, however, explicitly change the capacity of the container, e.g., by calling `circular_buffer::set_capacity()`.

By using the `push_back()` and `pop_front()` member functions you can use `boost::circular_buffer` as a FIFO. Example:

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void print(const boost::circular_buffer<int>& cb) {
   std::cout << "size: " << cb.size() << ", capacity: " << cb.capacity() << '\n';

   for (auto const& elem: cb)
      std::cout << elem << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}

auto main() -> int {
   // empty: size is zero
   boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);
   print(q);

   cb.push_back(0);
   print(cb);

   cb.push_back(1);
   print(cb);

   cb.push_back(2);  
   print(cb);

   // overwrites the oldest element: 0
   cb.push_back(3);
   print(cb);

   // overwrites the oldest element: 1
   cb.push_back(4);
   print(cb);

   cb.pop_front();
   print(cb);

   cb.pop_front();
   print(cb);

   // empty again
   cb.pop_front();
   print(cb);
}
```

Output:

```
size: 0, capacity: 3

size: 1, capacity: 3
0
size: 2, capacity: 3
0 1
size: 3, capacity: 3
0 1 2
size: 3, capacity: 3
1 2 3
size: 3, capacity: 3
2 3 4
size: 2, capacity: 3
3 4
size: 1, capacity: 3
4
size: 0, capacity: 3
```

---

#### Using `std::queue` with `boost::circular_buffer`

`std::queue` is a *container adapter* whose *underlying container* is `std::deque` by default. However, you can use `boost::circular_buffer` as `std::queue`'s underlying container as it implements the `front()`, `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_front()` member functions:

```
#include <queue>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
using FixedCapacityQueue = std::queue<T, boost::circular_buffer<T>>;

auto main() -> int {
   FixedCapacityQueue<int> fixedCapQueue(boost::circular_buffer<int>(3));

   fixedCapQueue.push(0);
   fixedCapQueue.push(1);
   fixedCapQueue.push(2);
   fixedCapQueue.push(3); // overwrites the 0
   assert(fixedCapQueue.front() == 1);

   fixedCapQueue.pop(); // pops the 1
   assert(fixedCapQueue.front() == 2); 
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that boost::circular_buffer<T> will overwrite the oldest element. However, author did not specify such requirement so this is a good answer anyway.

Comment: @Tihran yes. The circular buffer is ideal for use cases when older elements lose relevance compared to the newer ones. For example with log records. Other policies on what to do when inserting into a full queue would be (1) *just ignoring the new element to be inserted* and (2) *overwriting the newest element*. Both are trivial to implement with a `std::queue`, though. Regarding (2): `back()` returns a reference to the newest element.

Answer (score 2):

Using cycling custom container. Online example is here: https://ideone.com/0nEBZa

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

template <typename T, size_t N = 2>
class CyclicArray {
 public:
  typedef typename std::array<T, N>::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename std::array<T, N>::reference reference;
  typedef typename std::array<T, N>::const_reference const_reference;
  typedef typename std::array<T, N>::size_type size_type;

  ~CyclicArray() {
    while (size())
      pop_front();
  }

  void push_back(const T& v) {
    if (size_ + 1 > N)
      throw;
    new (&array_[(front_ + size_) % N]) T(v);
    ++size_;
  }

  void pop_front() {
    if (size_ < 1)
      throw;
    front().~T();
    ++front_;
    --size_;
    if (front_ >= N)
      front_ = 0;
  }

  const_reference front() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&array_[front_]);
  }

  reference front() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&array_[front_]);
  }

  size_type size() const {
    return size_;
  }

 private:
  size_type front_ = 0;
  size_type size_ = 0;
  std::array<char[sizeof(T)], N> array_;
};

int main() {
    std::queue<int, CyclicArray<int, 2>> queue;
    queue.push(1);
    queue.push(2);
    queue.pop();
    queue.push(3);
    int f = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    f = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
2
3
```