# C++ clarification regarding fixed size queue

Tags: c++

The following implements a fixed size queue. It is given here [C++ Create fixed size queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334492/c-create-fixed-size-queue)

```
template <typename T, int MaxLen, typename Container=std::deque<T>>
class FixedQueue : public std::queue<T, Container> {
public:
    void push(const T& value) {
        if (this->size() == MaxLen) {
           this->c.pop_front();
        }
        std::queue<T, Container>::push(value);
    }
};
```

My Question is what is `c` in the line `this->c.pop_front();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` is a protected member of [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) that holds the underlying container that the queue is based on.

Comment: Thanks 1201ProgramAlarm !! You are awesome.

Comment: @Didas if this answers your question, please accept the answer, as a gesture of appreciation for the person who took time to help you.